# Swapping indexes between records within a transaction

Tags: indexeddb

I'm having an issue with IndexedDB. I'm wanting to swap one of the unique indexes between records all within a transaction, but the transactions failing because the unique constraint of a record is being violated. This is odd to me because in that transaction I have rewritten the index that is being violated.

Is this a shortcoming of IndexedDB or am I doing something wrong?

Here is an example:

Starting indexes:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        id2: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        id2: 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        id2: 3
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        id2: 4
    }
]
```

Mutation indexes:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        id2: 4
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        id2: 3
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        id2: 2
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        id2: 1
    }
]
```

The transaction will fail because `id2` on `id` isn't unique since `id` 4 already has their `id2` set to 4.

Comment: Can you add a code sample? It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying (e.g. deleting then re-adding the records?) Also, "rewritten the index" makes me wonder if you're doing this in an upgrade transaction and deleting/creating a new index. Also, is the same behavior occurring in all browsers?

Comment: Looking at this again, I wonder if you're assuming that the uniqueness constraint is applied only when the transaction commits. That's not correct - the constraint is enforced on each request. So putting two values with swapped index keys would fail on the first put. It will be necessary to delete one, update the second, then re-put the (updated) first.

Comment: Yeah, that was my assumption. I thought if a transaction were used the system would be able to figure out that the constraint isn't being violated since the referencing record was also being updated. Here is the sample you requested. Sorry for the late response: http://codepen.io/kkirby/pen/mAbrLR?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks - I'll upgrade this to an actual answer then.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uniqueness constraint is applied on each individual request, not only when the overall transaction commits. So, for example:

```
var store = db.createObjectStore('s', {keyPath: id});
store.createIndex('by_idxid', 'idxid', {unique: true});

store.put({id: 1, idxid: 1111});
store.put({id: 2, idxid: 2222});

...

var tx = db.transaction('s', 'readwrite');
var store = tx.objectStore('s');
store.put({id: 1, idxid: 2222}); // this request will fail
store.put({id: 2, idxid: 1111});
```

You need to remove the record first, e.g.:

```
store.delete(2);
store.put({id: 1, idxid: 2222});
store.put({id: 2, idxid: 1111});
```